# PHP datastax driver - import large dataset

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax, datastax-php-driver

I need to insert a large xlsx (near 1 million rows) file in the Cassandra database and i'm having doubts about how to do it because of memory limitations.

I'm working with batch inserts but that is proving to be near impossible due to huge memory impact.

```
$batch = new Cassandra\BatchStatement(Cassandra::BATCH_UNLOGGED);

    foreach ($workbook->createRowIterator($myWorksheetIndex) as $rowIndex => $values) {

        if ($count > 0) {

            $time = is_int($values[3]) ? $values[2]->format('d-m-Y') . ' ' . date('00:00:00') : $values[2]->format('d-m-Y') . ' ' . $values[3]->format('H:i:s');
            $date = date_convert(DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $time));


            $prepared = $session->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO teste (ptd_assoc,ref_equip,dates) " .
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            );

            $batch->add($prepared, array(
                'ptd_assoc' => $values[0],
                'ref_equip' => $values[1],
                'dates' => new Cassandra\Timestamp(strtotime($date)),
                //  'load' => 3.4454
            ));
        }

        $count++;
    }

    $session->execute($batch);
```

I have successfully transform the xlsx into a more readable csv file. It's possible to `Copy` it to the database using the `Cassandra\SimpleStatement` method?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in well-formatted CSV, you may not have to write a custom importer. Have a look at the `cqlsh` `COPY FROM` command (`help copy;`).

Comment: 'COPY' is a cqlsh (shell) command and not a CQL (protocol) command.
If i want to do this with php, the only way is with a exec function call to cqlsh. Agree?

Comment: i installed cqlsh client to access my server but the copy command gives me this error `"<stdin>:1:'module' object has no attribute 'parse_options'"` no idea!

Comment: Sounds like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12284
If you must use PHP, I recommend writing asynchronous concurrent requests. Loading all rows in a single batch will cause problems on both client and server side.